# Why is this true? $\int \frac{du}{\tan u \cos^2 u} = \int \frac{d(\tan u)}{\tan u}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I can't understand why 
$$\int \frac{du}{\tan u \cos^2 u} = \int \frac{d(\tan u)}{\tan u}$$

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing? Is it a trigonometric identity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{d(\tan(u))}{du}=\sec^2(u)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(u)}$$

That's all.

Comment: But if you don’t know that derivative, use $$\tan(u)=\frac{\sin(u)}{\cos(u)}$$ take the derivative of that fraction, and use $$\sin^2+\cos^2=1$$

Answer (score 0):

let $y = \tan(u)$, then $dy = \sec^2(u).du $
first expression is nothing but $\int \frac{\sec^2 (u).du}{\tan(u)}   = \int \frac{dy}{y}$ and so is second .

okay it was my first time in mathjax please edit if something goes wrong

Comment: Put '\$' signs around your equations so it is recognised as MathJax equation. E.g. a^2 = b^2 doesn't work but $a^2=b^2$ does.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first integral $\int \frac{du}{\tan u \cos^2 u}$ is equal to $\log(tan(x))+C$ and in the second integral $\int \frac{d(\tan u)}{\tan u}$ we have that $\frac{d(\tan u)}{\tan u}$ is exactly the closed differential form $d(log(tan(u))$ (as say $\int dF=F+Constante)$